# extracting 2 words from string at the same time in java

Tags: java, substring, indexof

```
    "[17235_A, 17235_B, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]"   
    "[17235_C, 17235_D, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]"
    "[17235_E, 17235_F, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]"
```

I have a bunch of string as above, I want to extract the numbers `17235_A`, `17235_B` from first row and similarly others from 2nd and 3rd row. As you can see the numbers change on each row, I would be great if the substring code is generic. Your suggestions will help me a lot.

Comment: One way to do it would be by using regular expressions.

Comment: are those `String` come in fixed length and format? Have you tried with `subString`, `indexOf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "[17235_A, 17235_B, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]";

        String[] strArray = str.split(", ");

        System.out.println(strArray[0].substring(1)); //first number
        System.out.println(strArray[1]); //second number
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Since I need all 17235_A so I didn't subtract 1 from strArray[0] index.

Comment: It is for subtracting "[" symbol :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] result = string.split("," ,2);
```

result[0] and result[1] will be two substring you needed.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of regex will do this for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] myStrings = new String[] {"[17235_A, 17235_B, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]", "[17235_C, 17235_D, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]", "[17235_E, 17235_F, -1.0, 0.06838527, 1.0]"};
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[([^,]++),\\s*+([^,]++).*+$");
    for(final String string : myStrings) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }        
}
```

Output:

```
17235_A
17235_B
Done
17235_C
17235_D
Done
17235_E
17235_F
Done
```

Explanation of the regex:

- The `^` matches the start of the string
- The `\\[` matches the starting "[" (double esacped)
- The `([^,]++)` matches the content up to the first comma possesively, this is more of an optimisation than necessity
- The `,\\s*+` then matches a comma followed by any amount of whitespace (again possesively)
- The `([^,]++)` matches the content up to the next comma
- The `.*$` matches the content up to the end of the line (again possesively)

The two match groups now contain the required `String`s.

[This](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html) is a really good article on why to use possesive matches whereever possible.